# Is it possible to use a private secondary constructor to assign a val in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, field

I am trying to reduce code repetition by using a private constructor to assign a class field, but this does not seem to be possible.

What I'm trying to do is the exemplified here:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    private val bar: Int
    private val baz: Int

    constructor(bar: Int, baz: Int) : this(baz) {
        this.bar = bar
    }

    constructor(bar: String, baz: Int) : this(baz) {
        this.bar = bar.toInt()
    }

    private constructor(baz: Int) {
        this.baz = baz
    }
}
```

The alternative, that works, but which I am not satisfied with is doing the following:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    private val bar: Int
    private val baz: Int

    constructor(bar: Int, baz: Int) {
        this.bar = bar
        this.baz = baz
    }

    constructor(bar: String, baz: Int) {
        this.bar = bar.toInt()
        this.baz = baz
    }
}
```

To be clear I am not satisfied because of the replication of the `this.baz` assignment.

Is this simply not possible in Kotlin, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should rewrite this as:

```
class Foo(
    private val bar: Int,
    private val baz: Int, 
) {
    constructor(bar: String, baz: Int) : this(bar.toInt(), baz)
}
```

The `(Int, Int)` constructor has been made into a primary constructor, initialising all the values. And the second constructor delegates the primary constructor.

The first two secondary constructors that you declared in your non-working code cannot reassign the `val`s, because they delegate to another constructor, and it is assumed that that constructor initialises all the necessary properties. Though in this case, it doesn't, so you get another error.

Comment: This makes sense. So just to summarize: Make a primary constructor with fields of the preferred type, and add secondary constructors which has the purpose of converting alternative data types into the field's type. I think this is a nice way of looking at it. Thank you!

Comment: @humleflue Yes, exactly. Secondary constructor are like "convenience" constructors. (That's exactly what Swift calls them :D)

Comment: An alternative to a secondary constructor is a factory method in the companion object. If you define it as `operator fun invoke(…)` then calling it _looks_ exactly like a constructor call — but it can do as much processing as you need before calling the real constructor, and it can also return a cached object, subclass instance, etc. (The main drawback is that subclass constructors can't call it.)

Answer (score 4):

That can't work because your private constructor fails to initialize all properties.  You're treating it like a simple function call.

Why not do this?

```
class Foo {
    private val bar: Int
    private val baz: Int

    constructor(bar: Int, baz: Int) { 
        this.bar = bar
        this.baz = baz
    }

    constructor(bar: String, baz: Int) : this(bar.toInt(), baz) 
}
```

Comment: Or as other answer shows, that first constructor can be promoted to a primary constructor to simplify it.